# Create Dynamic URL in GWT

Tags: java, url, gwt

I am working on one application where I want to create dynamic URL appending my domain and the dynamic URL created can be shared with other users.
Like Example:
I have created one random string 'abcdef' and I want to create a dynamic url with this like 'http://domain.ext/abcdef/'. This URL now can be shared with other specific users, so those users can hit the same url to join on same page.

I want to create 'http://domain.ext/abcdef/' with 'abcdef' like dynamic string.
Please suggest, how I can do this with GWT ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() to the the base of your URL, then append what you need to that string.
Take a look at the javadoc in: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html